# first expression outside of function, what is it for?

Tags: python

I don't understand what my_trip_miles is even for.
This is the starting code:

```py
# 1) Complete the function to return the result of the conversion
def convert_distance(miles):
    km = miles * 1.6  # approximately 1.6 km in 1 mile

my_trip_miles = 55

# 2) Convert my_trip_miles to kilometers by calling the function above
my_trip_km = ___

# 3) Fill in the blank to print the result of the conversion
print("The distance in kilometers is " + ___)

# 4) Calculate the round-trip in kilometers by doubling the result,
#    and fill in the blank to print the result
print("The round-trip in kilometers is " + ___)
```

Couldn't we just write it like this?

```py
def convert_distance(miles): 
    km = miles * 1.6 

my_trip_km = convert_distance

print("The distance in kilometers is " + str(convert_distance))

print("The round-trip in kilometers is " + str(convert_distance * 2)
```

I am getting this part wrong too:

```py
convert_distance(55)
```

Comment: You need to return a value from a function so you can use the result. Also pass to the function the value you want it to act on.

Comment: You need to return a value from *convert_distance()*. You need to call *convert_distance()*. Use f-strings in *print()* or, for this trivial case, change plus to comma and do not call *str()*

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work fine:

```py
def convert_distance(miles): 
    km = miles * 1.6 
    return km

my_trip_miles = 55

my_trip_km = convert_distance(my_trip_miles)

print("The distance in kilometers is " + str(my_trip_km))

print("The round-trip in kilometers is " + str(my_trip_km * 2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on to the above, in case you have to keep the
my_trip_miles variable:

```py
my_trip_miles = 55 #just an input, which should be passed to method

my_trip_km = convert_distance( my_trip_miles ) #my_trip_km will store the output of convert_distance function
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it :)
In the function, you need to return the value.
And when you call the function, you need to give her the value for the convert.
You should remember when you call a function, You always need to add () - take a look at this website: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

```
KM = 0.621371192

# 1) Complete the function to return the result of the conversation
def convert_distance(miles):
    km = miles * KM
    return km


my_trip_miles = 55

# 2) Convert my_trip_miles to kilometers by calling the function above
my_trip_km = convert_distance(my_trip_miles)

# 3) Fill in the blank to print the result of the conversion
print("The distance in kilometers is " + str(my_trip_km))

# 4) Calculate the round-trip in kilometers by doubling the result,
#    and fill in the blank to print the result
print("The round-trip in kilometers is " + str(my_trip_km * 2))
```